# Check consecutive values and update field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have  a table here :

[image: Table1]

In the "week No"column ,
I have data for 5 consecutive weeks,every week I want to check these conditions-

1.Every week I will check the current week's points.If the points value is -10 for the current week and the previous week's points is also -10 then -40 is added  in table 2(below table) in totalpoints field.

2.Again we check it for current week and prevoius two week's points.If the score is -10 for three weeks consecutively the reward -100 for that person and added to total points field in table 2.(below table)

3.
Similarly for consecutive four weeks i.e current week and the previous 3 week's if points is -10 ,then add -200 to table2's total points field.

[image: Table 2]

Can anyone help me on how to achieve this . M using sql server .

Comment: should the result for Bob be less than -200, as he has all weeks with a score of -10?

Comment: 1) Please include your sample data as text (not image) in the question, or, better, as `INSERT` statements, so that others could test the queries. 2) Do you really want an answer that would run on all three versions of SQL Server? Please choose a tag for the version that you use.

Comment: For Bob, he will get -40 on week2 and again -100 on week3 and -200 on week4 .As the query will run every week ,it will check for previous week's points. @vkp

Comment: result table is the score of one particular week or is the running total of the sum of all weeks?

Comment: result table gets updated every week.So,it will contain result for all weeks.Is the 'total points' field in  table2.

Comment: so Bob will get -10 1st week, -10 and -40 2nd week, -10 and -100 3rd week, -10 and -200 the 4th week, -10 and -200 the 5th week? it should be -590?

Comment: yes exactly @MtwStark  that will be the score for Bob, whereas, Deepak will only get -40 on week5

Comment: i mean -40 will be added to total of Deepak on week5

Answer (score 2):

Here it is

```
; WITH 
u AS (SELECT * from (values (1,'Bob'),(2,'Deepak'),(3,'Brinda'),(4,'Chriss'),(4,'Chriss')) as d (usr,name)),
N AS (SELECT * from (values (1,1,-10),(1,2,-10),(1,3,-10),(1,4,-10),(1,5,-10),(2,1,50),(2,2,40),(2,3,30),(2,4,-10),(2,5,-10),(3,1,60),(3,2,20),(3,3,40),(3,4,-10),(3,5,20),(4,1,-10),(4,2,90),(4,3,50),(4,4,30),(4,5,50)) as d (usr,wk,pt)),
sc as (
    select w.*, case w.pt when -10 then (case w1.pt when -10 then (case w2.pt when -10 then (case w3.pt when -10 then -200 else -100 end) else -40 end) else 0 end) else 0 end x
    from n w
    left join n w1 on w.usr = w1.usr and w.wk = w1.wk+1
    left join n w2 on w.usr = w2.usr and w.wk = w2.wk+2
    left join n w3 on w.usr = w3.usr and w.wk = w3.wk+3
),
l as (
    select *, pt+x as total
    from sc
),
s as (
select usr, sum(total) total
from l
group by usr
)
select u.*,t.*
from s t
inner join u on u.usr = t.usr
```

If you want to see all details change final select in

```
select u.*,t.*
from l t
inner join u on u.usr = t.usr
```

in your database should be something like:

```
; WITH 
n as (
    select [EmployeeName], CAST(SUBSTRING([Week No.],5,10) AS INT) as wk, Points as pt  
    from YourTable --> Change this to your table
),
sc as (
    select w.*, case w.pt when -10 then (case w1.pt when -10 then (case w2.pt when -10 then (case w3.pt when -10 then -200 else -100 end) else -40 end) else 0 end) else 0 end x
    from n w
    left join n w1 on w.[EmployeeName] = w1.[EmployeeName] and w.wk = w1.wk+1
    left join n w2 on w.[EmployeeName] = w2.[EmployeeName] and w.wk = w2.wk+2
    left join n w3 on w.[EmployeeName] = w3.[EmployeeName] and w.wk = w3.wk+3
),
l as (
    select *, pt+x as total
    from sc
),
s as (
    select [EmployeeName], sum(total) total
    from l
    group by [EmployeeName]
)
select *
from s
```

Comment: thanks for the input.But lets say I have 100 employees.Then it would be a very very long query.is there an another way around ?

Comment: hey man, you have to use your tables not my example! :D instead of tables u and N you should use your tables

Comment: I mean, this query will not become longer with more data.. it is fixed length :) you only have to provide the data from your database, and transform "week1", "week2".. "weekn" in 1,2..n  - You can do it with the function CAST(SUBSTRING(WeekNo,5,10) AS INT) AS WK

Comment: Thanks a lot.let me take a look.M not able to get you.as u have already written it,will you plz take the pain to modify the above query and show me what exactly u mean.I have 100 employees and every week I get new data,on which this query will be applied.Anyways,thanks.God bless

Comment: The table fields are same as in my table

Comment: in you database do you have a users table with all [employee ID], [Employee Name]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126920/discussion-between-shivam-sharma-and-mtwstark).

Comment: yeah , i have the field names as in table above

Comment: .I want to update the "totalpoints" column in the second table above.So your solution  is not fetching me the correct result .

Comment: My solution recalc from scratch the totalpoints to write to Table2, what you miss? you have only to write the `UPDATE` command instead of the final `SELECT`